# При использовании canActivate в маршрутизации не заходит в привязанный Guard, а выдаёт ошибку ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

Tags: angular

Делаю простенькую авторизацию

app-routing.module.ts

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path : '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path : 'login', component: AuthorizationComponent },
  { path : 'services', component: ServicesPageComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]},
  ...
];
...
```

authorization.guard.ts

```
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

export class AuthorizationGuard implements CanActivate{

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

     console.log("localStorage = " +  localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

      if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
          return true;

      this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
  }
}
```

При переходе на services в AuthorizationGuard не заходит (пути в импортах прописаны правильно). В консоли ошибка:
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

Comment: а где декоратор `@Injectable()`?

Comment: в общем, решилось как @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})

Comment: читайте, пожалуйста, документацию, прежде чем спрашивать тут, вы сэкономите уйму времени :)

Comment: а ещё лучше пользуйтесь CLI. ng g guard auth и ангуляр всё за вас распишет и создаст

Comment: документацию читаю, но когда ты начинающий иногда тяжело бывает понять где ошибка